# Subalgebra of $C(X)$ that separates the points

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

I try to prove that

> Let $X$ be a compact space and $C(X) = \{f \colon X \to \mathbb F \mid f$ is continuous$\}$. Suppose that $ \mathscr A  $ is a subalgebra of $ C(X) $ that separates the points of $ X $ and $ 1\in \mathscr A $. Show that if $ x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n $ are distinct points in $ X $ and $ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb F  $, there is an $ f $ in $ \mathscr A  $ such that $ f(x_j) = \alpha_j $ for $ 1\leq j \leq n $.

How to prove it. Please help. It is from Functional analysis, by Conway.

> Let $X$ be a compact space and $C(X) = \{f \colon X \to \mathbb F \mid f$ is continuous$\}$. An subalgebra $\mathscr A$ of $C(X)$ is said to $\textit{separate the points}$ of $X$ if $x,y\in X$ and $x\not=y$, then there is an $f$ in $\mathscr A$ such that $f(x) \not= f(y)$

Comment: I would check out the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Locally_compact_version).  Should give you an idea of where to dive in!

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=a\neq f(y)=b$ either $a$ or $b$ is not zero. Say $b$. Then we can renormalize $f$ to
$$
f_{x,y}(z)=\frac{f(z)-a}b
$$
so that $f_{x,y}(x)=0$ and $f_{x,y}(y)=1$.

Now, let $x_1,...,x_n$ be any collection of $n$ points in $X$. For all $i=1,...,n$ consider the function
$$
F_i(z)=\prod_{j\neq i}f_{x_j,x_i}(z),\qquad z\in X.
$$
Then
$$
F_i(x_i)=1\quad\text{and}\qquad F_i(x_j)=0\quad\text{for all $j\neq i$}.
$$
At this point, the linear combination $G=\sum_{i=1}^na_iF_i$ will satisfy the required condition.